# JavaScript shortest way to map an array of objects to a new array of new objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of `person` objects, where each `person` have an array of `profiles` objects which consist of name and an image url, and a list of addresses objects which consist of `lat` and `long` properties, as follows:

```
var listOfPersons = [{
    addresses : [{lat:11, long:11}, {lat:22, long:22}],
    profile: [{image:"some_url1", name: "peter parker"}]
},
{
    addresses : [{lat:33, long:33}, {lat:44, long:44}],
    profile: [{image:"some_url2", name: "bruce wayne"}]
}];
```

I need to create a new array of objects, where each new object has an `image`, `long`, `lat` properties, for **each** set of `lat` `long`, as follows:

```
var expectedResult = [
{
    image:"some_url1",
  lat:11,
  long:11
},
{
    image:"some_url1",
  lat:22,
  long:22
},
{
    image:"some_url1",
  lat:33,
  long:33
},
{
    image:"some_url1",
  lat:44,
  long:44
}
];
```

What is the shortest way (in terms of writing code) to `map`\ `reduce` the first array into the second?

Comment: Fastest operationally? In terms of writing speed? Shortest?

Comment: In terms of writing speed, thanks for the comment

Comment: Also, can you have more than one thing in `profile`?

Comment: Yes, it is an array, but I will always take the first member

Comment: Can you have more than one profile in the array, or will the profile array will always only have a single member?

Comment: @OriDrori I can have many elements in the profile array, but I will always take the first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nested `Array.flatMap()` with `Array.map()` to iterate the array/address/profiles, and combine `image` and `lat`, `long` properties into a single object:

```js
const listOfPersons = [{"addresses":[{"lat":11,"long":11},{"lat":22,"long":22}],"profile":[{"image":"some_url1","name":"peter parker"}]},{"addresses":[{"lat":33,"long":33},{"lat":44,"long":44}],"profile":[{"image":"some_url2","name":"bruce wayne"}]}];

const result = listOfPersons.flatMap(o =>
  o.addresses.flatMap(({ lat, long }) => 
    o.profile.map(({ image }) => ({
      image,
      lat,
      long
    }))
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

If you always use just the 1st profile always, you can remove one level of `Array.flatMap()`:

```js
const listOfPersons = [{"addresses":[{"lat":11,"long":11},{"lat":22,"long":22}],"profile":[{"image":"some_url1","name":"peter parker"}]},{"addresses":[{"lat":33,"long":33},{"lat":44,"long":44}],"profile":[{"image":"some_url2","name":"bruce wayne"}]}];

const result = listOfPersons.flatMap(o =>
  o.addresses.map(({ lat, long }) =>  ({
    image: o.profile[0].image,
    lat,
    long
  }))
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with combined [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach).

The documentation states for `reduce()`:

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

I think the following can work for you:

```js
const listOfPersons = [{
    addresses : [{lat:11, long:11}, {lat:22, long:22}],
    profile: [{image:"some_url1", name: "peter parker"}]
},
{
    addresses : [{lat:33, long:33}, {lat:44, long:44}],
    profile: [{image:"some_url2", name: "bruce wayne"}]
}];

const result = listOfPersons.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  cur.addresses.forEach(e => acc.push({ ...e, image: cur.profile[0].image }));   
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Sinced you asked for shortest in writing code:

```js
var listOfPersons = [{addresses: [{lat:11, long:11}, {lat:22, long:22}],profile: [{image:"some_url1", name: "peter parker"}]},{addresses:lat:33, long:33}, {lat:44, long:44}],profile: [{image:"some_url2", name: "bruce wayne"}]}];

const res = listOfPersons.reduce((r,{addresses:a,profile:[{image}]})=> [...r,...a.map(o=>({image,...o}))],[]);

console.log(res);
```

Here's with formatting and better variable names:

```js
var listOfPersons = [{
  addresses : [{lat:11, long:11}, {lat:22, long:22}],
  profile: [{image:"some_url1", name: "peter parker"}]
},
{
  addresses : [{lat:33, long:33}, {lat:44, long:44}],
  profile: [{image:"some_url2", name: "bruce wayne"}]
}];


const res = listOfPersons.reduce((acc, { addresses: adr, profile: [{image}] }) =>
  [...acc, ...adr.map(a => ({image, ...a}) )],
[]);


console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var listOfPersons = [
  {
    addresses: [{ lat: 11, long: 11 }, { lat: 22, long: 22 }],
    profile: [{ image: "some_url1", name: "peter parker" }]
  },
  {
    addresses: [{ lat: 33, long: 33 }, { lat: 44, long: 44 }],
    profile: [{ image: "some_url2", name: "bruce wayne" }]
  }
];

var expectedResult = listOfPersons.reduce(
  (acc, person) => ([
    ...acc,
    ...person.addresses.map(
      address => ({ ...address, image: person.profile[0].image })
    )
  ]),
  []
)
```

This will give you what you want assuming you always want the first result from `.profile`

Answer (score 0):

```
var listOfPersons = [{
    addresses : [{lat:11, long:11}, {lat:22, long:22}],
    profile: [{image:"some_url1", name: "peter parker"}]
},
{
    addresses : [{lat:33, long:33}, {lat:44, long:44}],
    profile: [{image:"some_url2", name: "bruce wayne"}]
}];


var expectedResult = [];
expectedResult.forEach(person => {
    person.addresses.forEach(address => expectedResult.push({image: person.profile[0].image, ...address}))
});
```